# Foreign Language support on Android Emulator

Tags: android, character-encoding, emulation

I am working on an android program that is in Turkish. When I am compiling, emulator cannot encode the Turkish letters.

For example, on the menu, "Liman Giriş Çıkış Bilgisi" should be written. However there are irrelevant characters in place of the "ş", "ç", "ı" letters :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WGLmO.png]

I am working in Windows 7. There was no problem on Ubuntu.

What can be the problem and how could it be solved ?

Comment: If you want to provide a picture, put it on http://imgur.com and add a link in your question.

Comment: Are these Turkish words read from strings.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions to change the language of the emulator:

Open `Menu -> Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Locale -> set any locale here`

or programmatically as the following:

```
Locale locale = null;
Configuration config=null;
config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
locale = new Locale("tr");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
config.locale = locale;
```

Comment: There are no Turkish option on Settings.

Comment: I've added the code to my Menu class. But problem still occurs.. :S

Comment: Anil My qoestion link below please check it and give me proper solution Thanks!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452621/how-can-i-display-latin-words-in-android